# finding absolute path from a relative path in python

Tags: python, search, path

my question is pretty much what the title suggests.  my research has led me to try something like this:

```
import os
pathname = os.path.abspath("some/relative/directory")
print pathname
```

this problem is that whenever i do something like this, it simply returns whatever relative directory i gave it preceded by my python directory.  for example:

C:\Python27\some\relative\directory

which is not even an existing directory on my computer.  i understand that the python interpreter searches the working directory by default, but what i'd like to do is have it search my entire computer for an absolute path that contains the partial directory i specify.

the purpose of this is for me to create an exe (using py2exe) that can search for an arbitrary directory on any computer.  is there a method for doing this in the standard library or through some available module - or would i have to implement the algorithm myself?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to search your entire harddisk for a path that looks like that? Or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`abspath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) is based on [`getcwd`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd).  Most likely, your current working directory simply isn't what you expect.

You can change the code that launches your script, change directories manually, or just use [`chdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) in Python.

Comment: @Ben, no abspath doesn't do anything like that.  Such algorithms are more complicated then you might think.  For example, which [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) algorithm do you use, what do you do if there's more than one match, and what happens if the filesystem changes while you're searching?

Comment: hmm, i am pretty new to python, but i was hoping there would be an existing algorithm in some module... - is there a simple means of returning the first match found?

Comment: @Ben, you should edit your question and put something similar to the comment you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `os.path.realpath("my/relative/dir")`? Actually it seems the directory may not exist, but if it does, it will resolve symbolic links and whatnot.

Comment: i tried this also, but it still just returns C:\Python27\my\relative\dir - basically C:\Python27 + whatever string i pass in.