# can any body help? I get this error, and I cant solve it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am tring to run a python file and it start but after that give me this error. What I have to do to fixed this error, I am beginner with python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mininet_multicast_pox.py", line 318, in <module>
    mcastTest(topo, False, hosts)
  File "./mininet_multicast_pox.py", line 53, in mcastTest
    pox_process = Popen(pox_arguments, stdout=fnull, stderr=fnull, shell=False, close_fds=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can we see the code?
What have you tried to fix it?
Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the error is `No such file or directory`, and the missing file is `"./mininet_multicast_pox.py", line 318, in <module>`

Comment: I already run the file "./mininet_multicast_pox.py" and this is the function in the line 318 -----------------              mcastTest(topo, False, hosts)

Comment: do you think that the problem with the argument "topo"

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide an *absolute path* to you file.
Without that, the subprocess module can't find it.

The `os` module provides [routine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) for that.

Comment: dear Aluriak, thanks for your comment but How I can provide the path to my file?

Comment: An [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) is a path to your file that starts from the system root, something like `/home/koka/Documents/myfile.txt`, or `C:/Users/koka/Documents/myfile.txt`. There is lots of questions related to paths in Python. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909300/finding-absolute-path-from-a-relative-path-in-python), for instance.